# How can I get a .mbox file from Gmail in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to access a .mbox or other email file type of queried gmail threads.

For example, if I query for all emails from January, I want to then be able to download those emails as a .mbox file.

I am using Google Script, and the API does not mention any ability to take an array of threads and retrieve a downloadable file of them (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread).

Comment: Exporting to mbox is supported by GMail for archival purposes, it's not available for Google Apps Script. You would need to write such a script yourself.

Answer (score 0):

message.getRawContent() should get you most of the way there.

Perform your query.
Loop over each thread in the query results.
Loop over each message in each thread.
Use message.getDate() to make sure the message you're looking at is in the date range, and maybe other criteria you care about.
Once satisfied the message is one you care about, use message.getRawContent() and squirrel away that content.

When all done, take all your squirrelled away content and do something interesting with it.  Like put it into a file in drive or something.  You may have to experiment with any special escaping or From lines or something like that, but those should be minor tweaks.